# How to get last subelement of every element of a list?

Tags: r, list

I am trying to get the value of the **last** element of every subelement of a list.  The elements of the list are vectors of different length, so the index of the last sub-element is not constant between elements of the list.

I have searched SO but only found information for those looking to obtain, [for example, the second sub-element of every element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43014782/680068). This is not helpful for me since the elements of the list are of non-constant length.

I am only interested in solutions that do not involve using a for loop since my list is of length > 1 million.

Example data:

```
x <- list(a = 1:5, b = 1:10, d = 9:11)
```

Expected output is a list: `list(5, 10, 11)`

Comment: `lapply(mtcars, function(x){x[length(x)]})`? It depends a bit how the list is structured.

Comment: Another fun option is `mapply('[[', x, lengths(x))`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

We can use `lapply` and `tail`:

```
x <- list(a = 1:5, b = 1:10, d = 9:11)
last_elems <- lapply(x, tail, n = 1L)
```

As pointed out in the comments, to obtain a numeric vector instead of a one-element list, `vapply` is a good choice:

```
last_elems <- vapply(x, tail, n = 1L, FUN.VALUE = numeric(1))
```

Comment: Since a list of single element vectors is somewhat undesireable, we can also use `vapply(x, tail, 1L, 1L)` for a quick atomic vector result (or `sapply()`).

Comment: I am curious as to whether it's possible to use something like `sapply(x, "[", sapply(x, length)) ` (this unfortunately returns a matrix, but it's getting close)

Answer (score 2):

Using *purrr::map2*:

```
library(purrr)

x <- list(a = 1:5, b = 1:10, d = 9:11)
map2(x, lengths(x), pluck)
# $a
# [1] 5
# 
# $b
# [1] 10
# 
# $d
# [1] 11
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use `purrr::map_chr` along with `dplyr::last`:

```
map_chr(x, last)
```

This is particularly handy when working with tabular data

```
perfData %>% mutate(benchmark = map_chr(str_split(benchmark_name, "[.]"), last))
```

In the example, we extract the name part after the final `.`.
The same works with numbers using `map_int`, and so on see https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html

Answer (score 0):

Try `last` from the `data.table` package

```
> lapply(x, data.table::last)
$a
[1] 5

$b
[1] 10

$d
[1] 11
```