# R: Extract part of string with varying length

Tags: r, string, performance, apply, strsplit

I have a list of strings (very large, millions of rows) from which I want to extract specific parts.

I first split the string at the semicolon and then extract to specific sections. It's made a little more complicated as there are sometimes 3, sometimes 4 segments in one row. But the parts I'm interested in are always the last and second-to-last segment.

Example code:

```
dataStr = c("secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2")

splStr <- strsplit(dataStr, ";")
extr1 <- list()
extr2 <- list()

for (i in 1:length(splStr)) {
  extr1[i] <- head( tail(splStr[[i]], n=2), n=1)
  extr2[i] <- tail(splStr[[i]], n = 1)
}
```

It works, but it's much too slow. I would be grateful for any ideas of how to make this faster. I suspect this might be done with `apply`, but I couldn't wrap my head around it.

---

The issue was raised if it might be a duplicate question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143119/how-to-get-last-subelement-of-every-element-of-a-list-in-r) question. I think it's a bit different, as I want to extract the last two elements and the number of sections differs. Also, I haven't got the solution with `vapply` gotten to work on my real-world sample yet.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get last subelement of every element of a list in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36143119/how-to-get-last-subelement-of-every-element-of-a-list-in-r)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are better off with just using regexp here:

```
sub(".+; (.+?); (.+?)$", "\\2", dataStr)
```

That will grab the last item.

```
sub(".+; (.+?); (.+?)$", "\\1", dataStr)
```

That will grab the item before the last item.

Comment: Improved speed by a factor of 27 on my real-world sample.

Answer (score 2):

The `word` from `stringr` solution,

```
stringr::word(dataStr, -2, -1,  sep = ';')
```

You can then `strsplit` to get them as 2 different words, i.e.

```
do.call(rbind, strsplit(trimws(word(dataStr, -2, -1,  sep = ';')), '; '))
#      [,1]       [,2]      
# [1,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [2,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [3,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [4,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [5,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [6,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [7,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [8,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
# [9,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
#[10,] "secExtr1" "secExtr2"
```

Comment: I think this doesn't do the job: Both sections are still lumped together in the same cell.

Comment: Edited. I also used `trimws` to remove leading/trailing spaces

Comment: Great, works now - thanks! The regex solution is substantially faster, though.

Comment: Yes, I expected it would be but I am a bit regex-blind so I tend to avoid them as much as possible

Answer (score 1):

We can use `stringi` to make this faster along with `vapply`

```
library(stringi)
vapply(stri_split(dataStr, regex=';\\s*'), function(x) tail(x, 2), character(2))
```

Comment: This works on the example here, but fails on my real world example: `Error in vapply(splStr, function(x) tail(x, 2), character(2)) : 
  values must be length 2,
 but FUN(X[[5487]]) result is length 1`

Comment: @ulima2_  It is not clear when you have less than 2 cases, what to do

Answer (score 0):

It may be faster to do:

```
str_list <- lapply(splStr, tail, 2)
do.call(rbind, str_list)

      [,1]         [,2]       
 [1,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [2,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [3,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [4,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [5,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [6,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [7,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [8,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
 [9,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
[10,] "  secExtr1" " secExtr2"
```

Comment: Well it's the same. splStr is the split dataStr.

Comment: The regex method is actually faster (at least on this example set).

Answer (score 0):

```
> str_list <- lapply(dataStr, tail, 2)

> do.call(rbind, str_list)


      [,1]                                           
[1,] "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"               
[2,] "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"
[3,] "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"
[4,] "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"               
[5,] "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"               
[6,] "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"               
[7,] "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"
[8,] "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"               
[9,] "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"               
[10,] "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2"
```

**I am not sure that this is working?**

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the last and second last segments are always the same number of characters, this can be achieved in the following way with the `stringi` library.

I've also assumed you would like two lists as output.

```
library(stringi)

dataStr = c("secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secSometimes;  secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2",
            "secAlways;  secExtr1; secExtr2")

extr1 <- as.list(stringi::stri_sub(dataStr, from=-18, to=-11))
extr2 <- as.list(stringi::stri_sub(dataStr, from= -8))
```

Comment: Unfortunately they are not the same number of cases for me, sorry for the misleading example here.