# purrr::pluck - how to get last element of list

Tags: r, purrr, pluck

I am trying to extract the last element of nested lists. How can I do this with `purrr`? In the example below the results should be all the elements with the value "c".
I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42943533/r-get-last-element-from-str-split), but I am particularly interested in a solution with purrr.

Many thanks

```r
x <- list(list(1,2,"c"), list(3,"c"), list("c"))
x
#> [[1]]
#> [[1]][[1]]
#> [1] 1
#> 
#> [[1]][[2]]
#> [1] 2
#> 
#> [[1]][[3]]
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [[2]][[1]]
#> [1] 3
#> 
#> [[2]][[2]]
#> [1] "c"
#> 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [[3]][[1]]
#> [1] "c"

map(x, purrr::pluck, tail)
#> Error in map(x, purrr::pluck, tail): could not find function "map"
map(x, purrr::pluck, length(x))
#> Error in map(x, purrr::pluck, length(x)): could not find function "map"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-05-21 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I added purrr::map2 solution in the linked post, see if it works for you.

Comment: But based on your error, it looks like you didn't load the library: `library(purrr)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/7027288/680068

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `purrr::pluck` simply:

```
library(purrr)

map(x, ~ pluck(.x, length(.x)))
```

Or even easier use `dplyr::last`:

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)

map(x, last)
```

---

In just base `R`, reverse each list element and take the first item:

```
lapply(x, function(y) rev(y)[[1]])

lapply(x, \(y) rev(y)[[1]]) # R >= 4.1.0
```

Or

```
mapply(`[[`, x, sapply(x, length), SIMPLIFY = F)
```

Which would return a single vector if remove the argument `SIMPLIFY  = F` because the default is `TRUE`.

This works by iterating through your list `x` and the output of `sapply(x, length)` in parallel and applying it to the function `` `[[` `` which is an extraction operator.

Answer (score 4):

Will this work:

```
map(x, function(y) y[[length(y)]])
[[1]]
[1] "c"

[[2]]
[1] "c"

[[3]]
[1] "c"
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a nested list inside every list, I am not sure if it is intentional. In the current state, this would work -

```
library(purrr)

map(x, ~.x %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% tail(1))

#[[1]]
#[1] "c"

#[[2]]
#[1] "c"

#[[3]]
#[1] "c"
```

Also with `pluck` -

```
map(x, ~.x %>% unlist(recursive = FALSE) %>% pluck(length(.)))
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `base R` (`R 4.1.0`)

```
lapply(x, \(y) tail(y, 1)[[1]])
#[[1]]
#[1] "c"

#[[2]]
#[1] "c"

#[[3]]
#[1] "c"
```