# How to get the nth element of each item of a list, which is itself a vector of unknown length

Tags: r, list, vector, sublist

If we have a list, and each item can have different length. For example:

```
l <- list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4,5), c(5), c(6,7))
```

(In order to be clear, we will call objects in a list "items", and objects in the objects of list "elements".)

How can we extract, for example the first element of each item? Here, I want to extract:

```
1, 3, 5, 6
```

Then same question for the second element of each item:

```
2, 4, NA, 7
```

Comment: These would be called ***sublists***, if `l` was a list-of-lists; but anyway it's a list of vectors (not sure the term 'subvector' is used, but you get the idea). When you say *"How can we extract, for example the first element of each item? ...then the second...?"*, is your question really *"How to iterate over/flatten/unpack a list-of-vectors, breadth-first?"* i.e. Do you want to preserve the structure and index into it? or just transform it to a flat vector/list? In any case, there should be duplicates of each of those.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

We can create a function using `sapply`

```
fun1 <- function(lst, n){
         sapply(lst, `[`, n)
   }
fun1(l, 1)
#[1] 1 3 5 6

fun1(l, 2)
#[1]  2  4 NA  7
```

Comment: what is the meaning of `[` here ? where can I learn more about the use of sapply ? Thank you

Comment: @XRSC  It is an `?Extract` operator to extract the rows/columns of data.frame/matrix or elements of a vector.  More details you can get it from the `?Extract`

Answer (score 4):

`data.table::transpose(l)` will give you a list with vectors of all 1st elements, all 2nd elements, etc.

```
l <- list(1:2, 3:4, 5:7, 8:10)
b <- data.table::transpose(l)
b
# [[1]]
# [1] 1 3 5 8
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 2 4 6 9
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] NA NA  7 10
```

If you don't want the NAs you can do `lapply(b, function(x) x[!is.na(x)])`

Answer (score 0):

```
# the source list 
source_list <- list(c(1, 2), c(3, 4,5), c(5), c(6,7))

# the index of the elements you want 
k <- 1

# the results character vector 
x <- c()

for (item in source_list) {
     x <- append(x, item[k])
   }

print(x)
[1] 1 3 5 6
```