# R list get first item of each element

Tags: r, list

This should probably be very easy for someone to answer but I have had no success on finding the answer anywhere.

I am trying to return, from a list in R, the first item of each element of the list.

```
> a
[1] 1 2 3
> b
[1] 11 22 33
> c
[1] 111 222 333
> d <- list(a = a,b = b,c = c)
> d
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 11 22 33

$c
[1] 111 222 333
```

Based on the construction of my list d above, I want to return a vector with three values:

```
return  1 11 111
```

Comment: You can do `sapply(d, function(x) x[1])`

Comment: @amatsuo_net That did it thanks. You can post answer if you want to - can't believe I couldn't have found that myself!

Comment: Essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/43014782/8436923.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

`sapply(d, "[[", 1)` should do the trick.

A bit of explanation:

`sapply`: iterates over the elements in the list
`[[`: is the subset function. So we are asking sapply to use the subset  function on each list element.
1 : is an argument passed to "[["

It turns out that "[" or "[[" can be called in a traditional manner which may help to illustrate the point:

```
x <- 10:1
"["(x, 3)
 # [1] 8
```

Comment: I can't figure out why this works. Is it because of how a list is defined or because of how literally `sapply` works?

Comment: @gmarais Please also accept (check tick mark next to it) so we can consider it closed. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

You can do

```
 output <- sapply(d, function(x) x[1])
```

If you don't need the names

```
 names(output) <- NULL
```