# Extract same index elements from a list

Tags: r, list, apply

This question is an extension of [R list get first item of each element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44176908/r-list-get-first-item-of-each-element).

```
a <- c(1,2,3)
b <- c(11,22,33)
c <- c(111,222,333)
d <- list(a,b,c)

> sapply(d, function(x) x[1])
  [1]   1  11 111
```

The code above, extracts the first element of each list. My question is how can I generalize this to obtain a list which extracts all the same index elements and stores them in a list.

My desired output:

```
[[1]]
[1]   1  11 111

[[2]]
[1]   2  22 222

[[3]]
[1]   3  33 333
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following may help

```
sapply(1:3, function(k) sapply(d, function(x) x[k]),simplify = F)
```

or

```
Map(function(k) sapply(d, function(x) x[k]), 1:3)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have the same length for each element in your list , in this case 3, then you can also do,

```
split.default(unlist(d), rep(seq(3), 3))

#$`1`
#[1]   1  11 111

#$`2`
#[1]   2  22 222

#$`3`
#[1]   3  33 333
```

Where the 3 can be obtained by `unique(lengths(d))`

Answer (score 1):

We can use `transpose` with `flatten`

```
library(purrr)
d %>% 
    transpose %>%
     map(flatten_dbl)
#[[1]]
#[1]   1  11 111

#[[2]]
#[1]   2  22 222

#[[3]]
#[1]   3  33 333
```